# Creating a service in AKS with type=LoadBalancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm creating a k8 service in AKS with type=LoadBalancer. My intention is to expose this to the internet. I see that it has an external ip and works as expected.

My questions are:
1) what happens underneath the covers? does AKS create an azure load balancer resource? I don't see it in the portal.
2) does it cost extra money to have this service vs a ClusterIP service? if so, how much exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, AKS does create a load balancer resource. its in the worker nodes resource group, not in the aks resource group
2. yes it does, publicIp costs about 5$ a month, or something close to that, you can check azure calculator for exact price.

ps. ClusterIP isnt really an option, you cant use it for anything outside the cluster to talk to the service, afaik